# Delay in triggering of Messenger webhook

Tags: facebook, digital-ocean, chatbot, facebook-messenger

We've setup a [messenger webhook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook) for one of our [chat bots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chatbot). The same is successfully verified and saved:

[image: messenger webhook verified and saved]

The subscription events seems to be set correctly:

[image: subscription events set]

However, often we notice that no matter how many times we send message to the subscribed FB page, the POST webhook to handle users' input is never called.

The call starts when we do re-configure the events subscription for the app.

Our servers are running on DigitalOcean India region

Many other people are also experiencing this issue:

- [Messenger bot: delay in message reception](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/514753458893960/)
- [Random delays with receiving Messenger Webhooks requests](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/534039956953799/)
- [No Messenger Webhook sent at all on some page](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/171206476817162/)

Is there any temporary work-around for this bug atleast?

Comment: Please open a bug report on this and add the messenger-platform tag

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: @amuramoto The bug is already filed. I needed some temporary work around for now at least